# Load an image in navigation on hover without AJAX

Tags: javascript, performance, pageload

How can I load images like Amazon, where the "background" images only start loading in the fly-out as soon as the fly-out is triggered?

I've searched loads on this and every approach seems to either revolve around simply showing hidden images/elements or loading with AJAX.

My problem with this is that the tool that we use to track site performance, loads the hidden and/or AJAX content (at least: this is what I have been told RE the AJAX) and measures the content as part of the initial load - page load speed is one of our major KPIs and the tool that we use to track this with has been accepted as the standard ... so I have to find a way to only load the content on mouse enter or hover, thus lightening the page size considerably (like Amazon does). Once the images have loaded, they need to stay in the DOM until the page is refreshed.

Any ideas?

Comment: So you don't want to make another request, and also you don't want to load content and display it. The answer is simple. You can't.

Answer (score -1):

you can fire ajax on hover event and get the url of the image and inject it to the src attribute of image tag

Comment: Didn't he say without ajax? Or I misunderstood something?

Comment: may be without ajax, you have to store all you image url in some javascript variables, and on hover get the right url and add it to the src of img tag.